# Selecting text for copying with d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to make a color picker.
When hovering over an arc it should highlight the text inside so the user can just press ctrl-c to copy.
I already have the correct element. 
Searching for "select text" and such on Google doesn't yield very good results for this.

```
text.on('mouseover',function() {
               "this"- object is the text that should get highlighted.
       // Select text so user can press ctrl-c to copy...
});
```

I know there is the this.select() in jQuery but is there anything similar in d3.js (or regular javascript)?

Comment: There's nothing like this in D3.

Comment: Did you try the solution from this link(http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?459934-selecting-text-inside-lt-div-gt)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yogesh pointed to a good solution in his comment. It solved the problem very well.

[Sitepoint forum discussion](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?459934-selecting-text-inside-lt-div-gt#7)